# How are custom Iterables useful in JS? What are some common usecases of thing that can't be done easier any other way?

Tags: javascript, loops, iterator, iterable

I'm taking about making you own iterable using [Symbol.iterator] - I know how it technically works, but I cannot think of a genuine usecase. What can you do with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common use case is to create a custom iterator for a custom data structure.
For example, if you have a tree data structure, you can create an iterator that traverses the tree in a specific order (e.g. depth-first).